# Question about rotating objects through $n$ dimensional space.

Tags: geometry

This is a question I've been thinking about while playing with the concepts of rotation of objects in $n$-dimensions.

Take any object in the $(x,y)$ plane and bring it into the $(x,y,z)$ plane, then there exists a rotation such that when viewed from the $z$-axis and projected back down into the $(x,y)$ plane, the projected object looks like a $1$-dimensional object embedded into the $2$ dimensional plane.

So my question is: can this be generalized?  As an example, can I take a $3$ dimensional object through a rotation in $4$ space and have it look like a $2$ dimensional object embedded into a $3$ space?

Comment: Theoretically, you should be able to. But there's no way to be sure... you just have to rely on analogy.

Comment: If you enjoy this kind of thing, here's something to think about... if you look at a 2D circle straight on, it appears as a circle. But if you move your head, it looks like an ellipse. Does that mean that if a 4D being moved its head while looking at a sphere, it would look like an ellipsoid? Hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the maps
$$
i\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}
$$
$$
(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto (x_1,\ldots,x_n,0)
$$
$$
r\colon \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}
$$
$$
(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1})\mapsto (x_2,\ldots,x_{n+1},x_1)
$$
$$
p\colon\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to \mathbb{R}^n
$$
$$
(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1})\mapsto (x_1,\ldots,x_n)
$$
then $p\circ r \circ i$ maps any "$n$-dimensional" set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to an "$(n-1)$-dimensional" set. Note that $r$ is a rotation, and $i$, $p$ are the canonical inclusion and projection between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.